# https://management.azure.com/tenants api using asp.net core and c# code return The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I want to call https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01 api to call to get tenant list in my project, using asp.net and c# , but not able to get valid link.
if possible share sample of this.

I know how to call api, the problem is I dont get proper response,
I have refer below link to call api, but after calling organization api get exception 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'

I have taken Token using GetAccessToken() method

https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/how-to-call-the-azure-resource-manager-rest-api-from-c/

I got below information from Token

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To call this api, you need to genenate an access token for this api. To generate this token, you need an azure ad app with the specific api permission. For your 401 error, it's likely has wrong permission or does't contain the scope. You can debug your code and copy the access token and go to https://jwt.io/ to generate it.

Check if your token has the correct aud **https://management.azure.com** and scope **user_impersonation**:

Here's [the detail on this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) and I'll show you my detail on it.

[image]
[image]

Because of the delegated permission, you need to generate token via a user with ropc flow or auth code flow(this means not only the azure ad app, but you also need to use user name and password in the process of generating access token).

I think you can find a sample in this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code).

If you'd like you generate token and call api in your angular app, you can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular), pls note the sample calls graph api

[image]

If you prefer to call api in the backend app, you can send the token to the backend program because daemon applications only supports client credential flow.

Comment: I have added image of token information in question.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, I've seen the screenshot and I found that the tutorial you followed used client credential flow that means you generated an access token stand for an application, but the management api only supports delegated permission, so you can't use this flow to generate access token. I'll update my answer.